# Is it possible to merge casper-rw data with Ubuntu iso?

Tags: 14.04

I have a usb with Ubuntu 14.04 with casper-rw for liveusb persistence.
I would like to have one iso file with Ubuntu 14.04 (or other version) including the data I stored in casper-rw.

Is this possible and if yes, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible - yes, easy no.

The best way would be to do a standard installation on your usb.

IMHO data on a casper-rw is not as reliable as a standard install.

Other options would be to add a data partition to you usb.

If you wanted to convert , you would have to remaster the iso, which requries a moderate amount of knowledge and time consuming. IMHO the graphical tools are not as reliable as the command line and/or the debian live scripts (debian live scripts are in the ubuntu repoitories).

A detailed description of how to remaster your iso is a bit long and detailed for this site, see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

https://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/live-manual/stable/manual/html/live-manual.en.html

and ask a more specific question of you get stuck remastering the iso.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear. English is not my first language.
The problem I have is that I want to install CrossOver Linux and have my Windows programs ready inside a live environment. I have not found a way to install a Windows program e.g. Office 2010 via the command line.

To do this, I need access to the linux desktop before the remastered iso is built... But I don't know how I can achieve that

Comment: @JimvanDam - You will have to remaster the iso. the debian live scripts will be easiest (IMO) and the manual is available in multiple languages.

Comment: @bodi.zazen I will look into the debian live scripts manual for my language.